# Reset Input Values Upon Exiting

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, react-native, native-base

I am using native base input fields in my app like this:

```
const [startingPoint, setStartingPoint] = useState('');
const [endingPoint, setEndingPoint] = useState('');

<Input
  placeholder="My Input Value"
  onChangeText={text => setEndingPoint(text)}
  value={endingPoint}
/>
```

These values are wrapped inside View and Modals. Not any Form.

The inputting feature itself works correctly. However, when I exit the page (as in click back or cancel in my app) and come back, the values I wrote previously in the fields are still there. Is there any way I can reset them every time I exit the page?

This is how my modal looks like:

```
export const JourneyDetailsPage: React.FunctionComponent<JourneyDetailsPageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showJourneyDetailsPage,
}) => {
  const [startingPoint, setStartingPoint] = useState('');
  const [endingPoint, setEndingPoint] = useState('');
  const [showAvailableTripsPage, setShowAvailableTripsPage] = useState(false);

  const toggleAvailableTripsPage = () => {
    setShowAvailableTripsPage(showAvailableTripsPage ? false : true);
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={showJourneyDetailsPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={scaledJourneyDetailsStyles.container}>
          <View style={scaledJourneyDetailsStyles.searchTopContainer}>
            <View style={scaledJourneyDetailsStyles.searchTopTextContainer}>
              <Text
                onPress={toggleShowPage}>
                Cancel
              </Text>
              <Text>
                Location
              </Text>
              <Text>
                Done
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Item rounded style={scaledJourneyDetailsStyles.searchField}>
                <Icon
                  name="map-marker"
                  color="green"
                />
                <Input
                  placeholder="Start"
                  onChangeText={text => setStartingPoint(text)}
                  value={startingPoint}
                />
              </Item>
              <Item style={scaledJourneyDetailsStyles.searchField}>
                <Icon
                  name="search"
                  color="blue"
                />
                <Input
                  placeholder="End"
                  onChangeText={text => setEndingPoint(text)}
                  value={endingPoint}
                />
              </Item>
            </View>

            <View style={scaledJourneyDetailsStyles.offerContainer}>
              <Text style={scaledJourneyDetailsStyles.offerText}
              onPress={() =>
                setShowAvailableTripsPage(true)
              }              
              >Go</Text>
              <Text style={scaledJourneyDetailsStyles.offerText}>1 Person</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <AvailableTripsPage
          showAvailableTripsPage={showAvailableTripsPage}
          toggleShowPage={toggleAvailableTripsPage}
        />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: This means your Modal has not been destroyed, so it is still floating around even if it not visible. You should add more info on your Modal (component or library) in order to allow us to get it.

Comment: Could you see the updated qs? I added more code. Does that help? @leonardfactory

Comment: Which `Modal` is that? Are you using it from a library?

Comment: It's Modal from react-native. Nothing custom @leonardfactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Modal is still mounted after it is hidden, so data will still be floating around in the state.

What you can do is to use an Effect with `useEffect` in order to reset the state when the Modal is hidden, "watching" the `showJourneyDetailsPage` state, like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (showJourneyDetailsPage) return; // If shown, do nothing

  setStartingPoint('');
  setEndingPoint('');
  // ...
}, [showJourneyDetailsPage]);
```

Comment: that doesn't work. If I come back to the page, the text is still there

Comment: the modal isn't 'dismissed' probably. How can I do so?

Comment: Updated answer with alternative solution

Comment: I used the second option. In this case, the form resets if I go to the AvailableTrips page and come back. But if instead of going to AvailableTrips, I simply go back to the page before the Journey page, it doesn't reset and when I come back, the values are still there

Comment: Sorry, I red the variable name wrong. I was talking about `showJourneyDetailsPage`, which is the variable who leads Modal visibility.